# UTF-8 encoding gone missing after enabling mysqlnd

Tags: mysql, mysql5, mysql5.5, utf-8, mariadb

I've enabled mysqlnd on my PHP 5.4.26 server using MariaDB 10.0.8.

My SQL config contained this:

```
[mysqlnd]
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
```

It was all working fine when no mysqlnd was enabled. Since enabling it all special polish UTF-8 characters gone missing.

When I disable these two lines in server.cnf config all is working well again.

Since I don't like latin-1 encoding and I would like to keep UTF-8 I have a question does mysqlnd got UTF-8 by default and there is not need for these options ?

Comment: How do you enable your UTF8 encoding in your PHP application and database connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems these two lines are no longer needed ;)